# A closed form for $a_n=\frac{2n+2}{n(n+2)}a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{(n-1)(n+2)}a_{n-2}$, where $a_0=a_1=1$.

Tags: combinatorics

Given $a_0=a_1=1$ and for every $n\geq 2$
  $$a_n=\frac{2n+2}{n(n+2)}a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{(n-1)(n+2)}a_{n-2}$$
Find close formula for $a_n$

I've had this question today at the test but i couldn't solve this.

Comment: What sorts of techniques for solving recurrence relations are you familiar with? There are a few potential routes that come to mind.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer 1.homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients 2. generating functions 3. not-homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients

Comment: Partial fractions might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply $(n+2)n!$ on both sides,

$$(n+2)n! \times a_n
 = 2(n+1)(n-1)! \times a_{n-1}
 + n(n-2)! \times a_{n-2}$$

Let $u_n=(n+2)n! \times a_{n}$, we have

> $$u_n=2u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}$$